# Class 'Breadcrumbs' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [this](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs) breadcrumb package

First, I ran this command line:

`composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.x`

I also followed these steps:

Add the service provider to providers and alias in my `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "laravel": {
          "providers": [
              "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider"
          ],
          "aliases": {
              "Breadcrumbs": "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\Facades\\Breadcrumbs"
          }
      }
    }
},
```

In my `routes/breadcrumbs.php` i have these codes

```
// Home
Breadcrumbs::for('home', function ($trail) {
    $trail->push('Home', route('home'));
});

// Home > Contact Us
Breadcrumbs::for('contact-us', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push('Contact Us', route('contact-us'));
});

// Home > About
Breadcrumbs::for('about', function ($trail) {
    $trail->parent('home');
    $trail->push('About', route('about'));
});
```

In `routes/web.php` i have this

```
Route::get('contact-us', 'ContactUsController@ContactUs')->name('contactus');
Route::post('contact-us',[
  'as'=>'contactus.store',
  'uses'=>'ContactUsController@ContactUsPost'
]);
```

and in my `contactUs.blade.php` i have this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     {{ Breadcrumbs::render('contactus') }}
</div>
```

When i go to the contact us page i see this error

```
Class 'Breadcrumbs' not found (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blabla/Frontend/resources/views/contactUs.blade.php)
```

I also tired `composer update davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs` and `php artisan package:discover` but still no luck

Anyone have any idea what i'm missing or doing wrong? Kind of new to Laravel, been using Yii before this. **I'm using Laravel version 5.8.3**

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the version of Laravel might be relevant here, can you add it to your question?

Comment: Never seen service provider and aliases being set in composer.json. This is normally done in `config/app.php`

Comment: @Thomas sorry forgot. I'm using v5.8.3

Comment: @kerbholz oh!!! hahah thanks. works now. sorry new to laravel!

Comment: ;) Glad it works

Comment: You don't have to add the `extra` section to `composer.json` - that's for the package itself to do (which looking at their code, it does). Try removing it and running `composer update` again? Maybe it interferes with the auto-discovery from the package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @kerbholz for the solution. Moved the code below in my `composer.json`

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "laravel": {
          "providers": [
              "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider"
          ],
          "aliases": {
              "Breadcrumbs": "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\Facades\\Breadcrumbs"
          }
      }
    }
},
```

to my `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
        .....
        DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::class
],
'alias' => [
        .....
        "Breadcrumbs" => DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Facades\Breadcrumbs::class 
]
```